# Programmatically disabling NSButton removes border

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsbutton

I've got this sidebar with two `NSButton` and one `NSTextField`. The action linked to the text field disables the two buttons, runs an algorithm and then enables them again. The same action is called by the first button.

[image: Sidebar Image]

If I click on the first button everything is okay. If I press enter while editing the text field, the action is run okay, but the two buttons get disabled *and* their border seems to be removed. After the action has been finished, they display as just white text. They don't look like buttons anymore.

[image: Borderless Buttons]

Why does this happen?

Code :

```
- (IBAction)run:(id)sender {
    [self setControlsEnabled:false]; // Disable controls
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self runAlgorithm];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setControlsEnabled:true];
        });
    });
}

- (void)setControlsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    [generateButton setEnabled:enabled];
    [solveButton setEnabled:enabled];
}
```

Comment: Hi Broseph Huntington, could you provide your buttons setups, please.

Comment: [Here's example code](https://files.fm/u/9mkcnuvc#_)

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce your issue on my mac, *but*, I found that you call UI API on a background thread: `[[Algorithm sharedAlgorithm] setStrategy:(int)[algorithmMenu indexOfSelectedItem]];`. It is not allowed in Cocoa and leads to unpredictable results. Also, I found that you have a lot of issues with memory management. Do you use Xcode IDE? Try to analyze you code using Xcode IDE via `Product => Analyze` menu item and you will see this errors.

Comment: That's not UI API though. All the UI code should be run from the main thread. If you enter a value in the text field, then press enter, what happens? Does it display the buttons properly?

Comment: Yep, if I enter a value in the text field, then press enter - buttons rendered properly.

According to UI API. This error I've got from Xcode:

Comment: Odd. May be a bug they fixed, I'm gonna check what happens on Sierra (I was running on Yosemite).

Comment: According to UI API. Are you sure? This error I've got from Xcode:
`Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[NSPopUpButton indexOfSelectedItem]
Backtrace:
4   Intersection Algorithms  0x0000000100002564 __55-[IntersectionWindowController calculateIntersections:]_block_invoke + 148
...
2018-06-20 21:44:51.849263+0300 Intersection Algorithms[58755:14175482] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[NSPopUpButton indexOfSelectedItem]`

Comment: Yeah works on Sierra. Probably a bug.

Comment: `indexOfSelectedItem` is a method of a `NSPopUpButton` and you call it from a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue`. `global_queue` is not `main_queue`.

Comment: Error is too long, but here is some text:
`Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[NSPopUpButton indexOfSelectedItem]
Backtrace:
4   Intersection Algorithms  0x0000000100002564 __55-[IntersectionWindowController calculateIntersections:]_block_invoke + 148

...

2018-06-20 21:44:51.849263+0300 Intersection Algorithms[58755:14175482] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[NSPopUpButton indexOfSelectedItem]`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get that error, but that's useful.